# Time type precision

Tags: postgresql

I have a field with type "time without time zone" declared in one of our tables. The problem is that times (via JDBC) is stored with milliseconds which I do not want.

```
09:55:10.137
```

we need just the seconds (in order for application to be compatible and run on a DB2 based environment where times are stored only with seconds)

```
09:55:10
```

Can I alter that field and how ?

Thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). Timestamp without time zone can be specified as:

```
timestamp [ (p) ] [ without time zone ]
```

where `p` is required precision.

Quoting documentation:

> time, timestamp, and interval accept an optional precision value p
>   which specifies the number of fractional digits retained in the
>   seconds field. By default, there is no explicit bound on precision.
>   The allowed range of p is from 0 to 6 for the timestamp and interval
>   types.

Test:

```
drop table if exists test;

-- zero fractional digits after seconds
create table test(mytime timestamp(0) without time zone);

-- now() returns current time including microseconds
insert into test values(now());

select * from test;
----
2014-06-05 10:42:11
```

Comment: Thanks, could not find the direct explanation of the different (p) options in documentation though. 
But your answer did the trick:
    alter table inv_period_comment alter column comment_time type time(0);

//Darkosa